# How to get the picture's directory/url into a database?

Tags: php, image

I know this question has been asked many times before, but i still can't understand it even if i do many times. I need someone to explain things to me but i have no help here. I hope you guys can help me with my coding.

I try to do an upload page, it's working just fine but i just don't understand how people can grab the image location directory/url and save it into a database. I can show the image but the image is being shown from the folder. I mean i think the directory of the image after it being uploaded into a `uploads/` folder isn't being save into the database.

I have a database name `images` and the table `images`. And the columns are `id`, `name`, and `ext`.

Here is my coding for `index.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<!--Upload form-->
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

</form>

<?php
//include the connect.php file

include ('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     {


    //location, where the image will be saved
    $loc= "uploads/";

    if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png" 
         || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" 
         || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg" 
         || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
        {
            //script

            $file=explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


            mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES ('','".$file[0]."', '".$file[1]."')");
            $id = mysql_insert_id();

            $newname = "$id.$file[1]";

            $path = "$loc$newname.ShowUploadKatSini.php";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
            echo"Your image has been uploaded successfully. Visit this link to see ur image <a href='$path'>Click HERE</a>.";


        } 
        else 
        {
            echo"Invalid file!";

        }



     }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is for `connect.php`:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root");

//select database
mysql_select_db("images",$connect);

?>
```

My real question is how to grab the picture's directory/url into a database and make the pictures that i upload shown in certain page, let say the page name `dress.html`

Comment: And also, don't use `mysql_` functions anymore. They're deprecated. Use the [mysqli](http://nl1.php.net/mysqli) extension or even better: [PDO](http://nl3.php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

You INSERT query is not correct

This

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES ('','".$file[0]."', '".$file[1]."')");
```

Should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (`name`, `ext`) VALUES ('".$file[0]."', '".$file[1]."')");
```

Comment: And of course, you **always** want to escape your values.

Comment: and how is this helping me? If i put `('name', 'ext')` it will not insert into the database

Comment: Your INSERT query needed to specify the table columns you wanted the data to be inserted into, the syntax of the query was wrong.  What error message are you getting when you try to insert?

Comment: Nothing. But if i put `('name', 'ext')` at the `INSERT INTO images` the data that suppose to be inserted on the database aren't inserted

Comment: After your mysql_query command use this to see if you are getting any errors. echo mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error();